# How to skip including a header file to a specifc C/CPP file

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

I would like to skip including a header file in my newly developed code.
I am working on two projects (or solutions) in visual studio. Both have dependancy on each other.
Suppose,

`Project_1.sln` contains one header file as `MyHeader.h`. `MyHeader.h` contains an `enum`,

`MyHeader.h file`

```
   typedef enum{
    hello, hi, bye
    }MyEnum;
```

In `Project_2.sln` contains one header file with different name as `Header2.h`. `Header2.h` also contains `same enum` as `MyHeader.h` from `Project_1.sln`.

`Header2.h file`

```
   typedef enum{
    hello, hi, bye
    }MyEnum;
```

So, I have tried using /FORCE:MULTIPLE, but it's not working.
I can not change the enum names also, because they are getting used in many places in both the projects.

When I am using in my `MyTest.c` file I need to use both the `header files`.

`MyTest.c File`

```
#include "Header2.h"
#include "Another.h"
```

Here `Another.h` file internally includes `MyHeader.h` file.
Instead of moving the `enum` to other file, are there any other solution?
Please help me, how can I resolve this problem.

Comment: Put the `enum` in a file `MyEnum.h` and include that wherever it is needed?

Comment: Either forward-declare the enum and do the #include's in your .c file(s) or put the enum in it's own .h and 'include in the dependent headers.

Comment: @All:- Dipto's answer worked for me.. Anyways Thanks to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may use conditional compilation of the `enum` part as:

```
#ifndef MY_ENUM
#define MY_ENUM
   typedef enum{
   hello, hi, bye
   }MyEnum;
#endif
```

in both the files.

Answer (score 2):

In Header2.h:

```
#ifndef HEADER2_H
#define HEADER2_H
...current contents of Header2.h
#endif // HEADER2_H
```

And in Another.h:

```
#ifndef ANOTHER_H
#define ANOTHER_H
...current contents of Another.h
#endif // ANOTHER_H
```

But having this sort of 2-way dependency is generally a sign of confused design, and you should try to resolve it, probably by adding third module.

---

Addition after re-reading the question: If these are actually separate enums, which just happen to have same name and contents, then you should put both to [a different namespace](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/). And if they are same enum, then define it in just one header file, which you include to both `Header2.h` and `Another.h`, and which is also protected by ["include guard"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), like shown above.